# Si può dire "mangiare melone"?

Tags: word-usage, grammar, articles

A volte uso un sito web nel quale posso fare esercizi scritti in italiano che poi vengono corretti da utenti italiani. In uno di questi esercizi ho scritto questa frase:

> Se dovessi per forza **mangiare melone**, preferirei quei meloni che tutti qualificano come "cattivi meloni" perché non sanno di niente.

Quasi tutti gli utenti però mi hanno corretto la frase in questo modo:

> Se dovessi per forza **mangiare un melone**, preferirei quei meloni che tutti qualificano come "cattivi meloni" perché non sanno di niente.

Il problema è che i meloni che abbiamo dalle mie parti sono molto grandi in modo che non si mangia mai un melone tutto intero. La mia domanda è: si può dire "mangiare melone" così come si dice "mangiare riso"?

Comment: Ti hanno corretto sbagliando. “Mangiare melone” è addirittura preferibile a “mangiare un melone” in questo contesto: mica ti mangi un melone intero, come giustamente osservi. Prova a obiettare che si *mangia prosciutto* e, in genere, non si *mangia un prosciutto*.

Comment: @egreg: La cosa curiosa è che questo esercizio è stato corretto da parecchi utenti, ma nessuno di loro ha accettato il mio "mangiare melone". Come ho detto, quasi tutti hanno corretto "mangiare un melone", una persona ha messo "mangiare del melone" e un'altro ha scritto "mangiarlo" perché io avevo menzionato prima il melone (quest'ultimo penso avesse ragione).

Comment: @Charo: concordo, hanno sbagliato a correggerti. Per motivi strettamente grammaticali, aveva ragione chi ti ha corretto "del melone", considerando "del" una forma partitiva, che però in italiano non usiamo nel parlato e sta ormai sparendo anche dallo scritto, pure quello più come controllato (tra le principali case editrici, solo Adelphi continua a consentirlo).

Comment: Riguardo alla domanda la risposta sarebbe: sì. Possibile che possa essere la risposta più corta in SE? :)

Comment: Credo che _mangiare melone_ sia non corretta, e comunque non la userei, semmai _mangiare del melone_. @Benedetta, io lo uso! ps. vedo ora [wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articolo_partitivo}) e mi sembra Ok.

Comment: Correggerei  anche l'apodosi _Se dovessi per forza mangiare del melone, preferirei mangiarne **di** quelli  che tutti qualificano come "cattivi meloni" perché non sanno di niente._

Comment: @mario di dove sei? Entrambe le tue correzioni mi suonano sbagliate. Io sono di Torino

Comment: @edc65 misto, toscano con influenze pugliesi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sì, si può certamente dire.

*Mangiare un melone* significa che lo si consuma tutto intero. Per esempio

> *Ci mangiamo un melone?*

sarebbe la forma corretta per proporre a una o più persone di mangiarlo.

Nel tuo caso la scelta è tra nessun articolo o l'articolo determinativo, per indicare la specie:

> Se dovessi mangiare (il) melone, …

Il caso è analogo a *mangiare riso*, come giustamente osservi, sebbene ci sia qualche importante differenza: il riso fa parte della categoria che in inglese si chiamerebbe “uncountable” e infatti si dice *un chicco di riso* se si vuole parlare dell'unità minima di riso. Ma si dice comunemente *bere caffè*, *mangiare gelato* e così via; nel tuo caso, *melone* indica la specie generica.

Può darsi che la forma “grammaticalmente corretta” sia quella con l'articolo determinativo (ma non ci giurerei) che nel caso in esame andrebbe benissimo.

Un caso leggermente diverso è quello del gelato o di altro alimento che si consuma interamente. Qui l'articolo indeterminativo andrebbe bene, ma proprio perché di solito si mangia tutto un gelato.

Un caso in cui uno qualsiasi dei modi va bene è quando si ordina al ristorante:

> Vorrei risotto agli asparagi
>   Vorrei un risotto agli asparagi
>   Vorrei il risotto agli asparagi

Answer (score 2):

Un melone intero è troppo, se proprio vuoi mettere qualcosa tra "mangiare" e "melone" ci va una preposizione articolata del tipo

> - Se devo mangiare del melone... (una parte)
> - Se devo mangiare melone... (un po di)
> - Se devo mangiare un melone (intero)

Answer (score 1):

Dire "mangio melone" porta una certa ambiguità. Può significare "mangio del melone in questo specifico pasto", e potrebbe essere usato per ordinare del melone ad un cameriere al ristorante.

Ma può anche significare che il melone rientra nella lista dei cibi che mangio: allo stesso modo, posso dire "io mangio carne" per dire che non sono vegetariano. Quest'ultimo significato ben si adatta alla situazione, perché "se dovessi per forza mangiare melone" presuppone che io non mangi melone, perché non mi piace.

Secondo me tutte le forme sono valide, con significati lievemente diversi:

> Io devo per forza mangiare melone

significa: il dottore mi dice che per la mia salute devo mangiare melone regolarmente.

> Io devo per forza mangiare un melone

significa: devo mangiarne uno, per scommessa o per qualche altra strana ragione.

> Io devo per forza mangiare del melone

significa: devo mangiare un po' di melone.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao! Purtroppo non puoi dire solamente "mangiare melone".

L' "oggetto" della frase (in questo caso il melone) necessita di un articolo determinativo ("il", perché è un oggetto maschile), indeterminativo ("un", perché è un oggetto maschile) o di una forma partitiva usando "del".

- Usando "il" ti riferisci al melone conosciuto all'interno del contesto della discussione, quello cui ti state riferendo tu e il tuo interlocutore ("Voglio mangiare il melone", proprio quello lì, specifico).
- Usando "un" ti riferisci ad un generico melone non per forza sottinteso nella discussione ("Ho voglia di mangiare un melone", quindi uno qualsiasi).
- Usando "del" comunichi la tua voglia di mangiare una parte di un melone ("Vorrei mangiare del melone").

In Italia nessuno userebbe mai "mangiare melone" senza aggiungere un articolo, a meno che "melone" sia il nome o la marca di un prodotto chiamato in questo modo.

Comment: La tua affermazione che “nessuno userebbe mai” quella forma suona un po' dubbia, visto che il sottoscritto e tutti quelli che hanno risposto finora la considerano normale.

Comment: @DaG Sono italiano e non userei mai quell'espressione nel parlato, non avrebbe alcun senso. Nessun madrelingua italiano ti dirà mai che è un'espressione normale, perché qui non si usa

Comment: Anch'io sono madrelingua italiano, io la userei, e come vedi da altre risposte non sono il solo: quindi qui *si usa*. Non puoi fare un'affermazione categorica (“nessuno userebbe...”) solo sulla base della tua esperienza personale.

Comment: Non è una questione di esperienza personale, è una frase che è palesemente ambigua e sono certo al 100% che nel linguaggio parlato si preferirebbero altri tipi di espressione più complete. "Andiamo a mangiare melone" è un'espressione monca che durante una discussione potrebbe lasciare aperto a interpretazioni su ciò che si intende dire (oltre ad avere un suono tipicamente straniero e poco naturale nell'italiano comune parlato). Sicuramente si può utilizzare (potenzialmente si può usare tutto) ma considerarla "normale", per me, è decisamente troppo.

Comment: Visto che a te fa questo effetto e ad altri no, ciò stesso dimostra che si tratta di esperienza personale, no? Non è una critica: per esempio, a me suona insolito l'uso di “seguitare”, rispetto a “proseguire” o “andare avanti”, ma non ha nulla che non vada.

Comment: A me l'unica frase con parvenza normale è del tipo "a me, mangiare melone irrita i denti" o cose simili. Ma probabilmente, senza pensare, direi "il melone", e questo senza intendere certamente un melone preciso. Quindi non concordo con la risolutezza di "in Italia nessuno userebbe 'mangiare melone'", ma sono sostanzialmente d'accordo con @Phoenix.