# Difference between "mangi pane", "mangi di pane" and "mangi il pane"

Tags: nouns, articles

What's the difference between "mangi pane", "mangi di pane" and "mangi il pane"?

I found some sentences at http://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/pane+che+mangi and I'm uncertain about the choices.

And why can't we say "mangi mela" and we have to say "mangi la mela"?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Where have you seen "mangi di pane"?

Comment: Related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/7146.

Comment: Another related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7232/si-pu%C3%B2-dire-mangiare-melone

Comment: And *_mangi di pane_ is undoubtedly wrong. If anything, _mangi del pane_.

Comment: "Vedo si mangi di nuovo pane" this is where I saw it

Comment: @AnnaKompogiannopoulou In the case “si mangi di nuovo pane”, the part “di nuovo” constitutes an adverb, meaning “ancora” or “nuovamente”.

Comment: "Vedo si mangi di nuovo pane", even substituting “di nuovo” con “nuovamente” is quite a strange sentence. Where did you find it?

Comment: http://context.reverso.net/traduzione/italiano-inglese/pane+che+mangi

Comment: I can't find the sentence you mention. Was it perhaps “Vedo che mangi di nuovo pane”?

Comment: Exactly, yes; it's awkward phrasing?

Comment: “Vedo che mangi di nuovo pane” is perfectly fine; it's “Vedo si mangi di nuovo pane”, as you wrote, that is not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Pane* can be in generic or proper sense. In the first sentence

> Non mangi pane dal tempo delle medie

is is used in generic sense (*any kind of bread*). In the second sentence

> Soffocherai se mangi il pane in quel modo

it is used in proper sense (*that particular piece of bread*).

In the sentence *Vedo che mangi di nuovo pane* the part *di nuovo* is an adverb (locuzione avverbiale), not to be interpreted as a preposition followed by an adjective modifying *pane*. It's an inseparable entity which means *nuovamente*, *ancora* (in English it could be rendered as *again*).

Let's examine instead *Tu lo mangi il pane, vero?”. This is very colloquial, a bit more formal it should be *Tu mangi pane, vero?”

Actually the choice between no article and article is not clearcut. For instance, I would prefer

> È solo che non voglio che Dylan mangi pane bianco

where the site adds the article. Both versions are acceptable, though.

To the contrary, *mela* is the particular fruit and *mangi mela* is not acceptable, because one eats that apple; consider that bread comes in various formats and in olden times it used to be baked in quite big forms.

On the other hand, we say *succo di mela*, not *succo della mela*, because the juice is made from several apples and a particular apple cannot be distinguished.